# Chrome Drag&Drop URL from address bar to desktop creates a file shortcut but is missing the website icon

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, internet-explorer, icons, file-shortcut

Chrome's file shortcuts that it creates is missing the icon from the website. I've used internet explorer and if I drag-and-drop from the address bar to the desktop, it creates a file shortcut with the icon of the website.

[chrome created file shortcut - just generic icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqEHa.png)

[internet explorer created file shortcut - has proper icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qwqp.png)

is there a clever way to get this functionality in chrome as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way to do this in Chrome (Chrome 68):

1. Go on the website you want a shortcut from
2. Click on the menu button (three dots at the top right corner)
3. Go to "More tools"
4. Click on "create shortcut"
5. Type in a name for the shortcut and finally click on "create"

Then you should have a shortcut with the website's favicon on your desktop.

[Step by Step illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlV5F.png)